# Change the width of container when scrolling the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing the website http://advm.space/kublse/

The task is that I want to change the width of centre block when it reaches the end of the sidebars (screenshot).

Thank you in advance !
[image]

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I found the solution but it works only when I'm pressing the button. 
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('.box').toggleClass('change');
});

.height {
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
    max-height: 500px;
}
.width {    
    max-width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;    
}
.change {
    &.height {
       max-height: 1000px;
    }
    &.width {
       min-width: 1000px;
    }
}
So it is not what I need. Just have no idea from where to start. Think I need some kind of anchor by reaching which the width would change

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple way to change the container or your content div block's **width** when the user scrolls to the end of an element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('#sidebar'); // when user reach the end of sidebar
   var offset = startchange.offset();
    if (startchange.length){
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $(".yourDiv").css('width', '1000px'); // check if the user reached to the end of sidebar, if yes then change the width of your div.
       } else {
          $('.yourDiv').css('width', '630px'); // if the user hasn't reached to the end of sidebar or he scrolled back, this is the default width value.
       }
   });
    }
});
```